# Why is chloridric acid used in salt bridges?

Tags: electrochemistry

I've been planning an experiment on how to make galvanic cells and during my research I came across an article in which chloridric acid was used, along with a soluble salt and agar-agar,  in salt bridges. 
Since then, I've been wondering why chloridric acid was added to agar-agar.

Thanks in advence.

Answer (score 2):

Any ionic solution can function as a salt bridge. Having it acid based helps with the fast conduction paths of H+ in water.

The critical question is the leak rate. Any salt bridge will leak some amount of the ions into the solution. Good ones leak less, bad ones leak more.

So if you cannot tolerate any acidity in your solution, don't use an acid. Similarly, if you cannot tolerate any chloride in your solution, this would be a bad choice.